# I am trying to run PHP artisan tinker command on the command line and it showing this error

Tags: laravel-artisan, laravel-6.2, tinker

```
ErrorException :mkdi<>: File exists

at c:\xampp\php\codehub\vendor\spy\psysh\configuration.php:363
359: $this->runtimeDir = configpaths::getRubtimeDir<>;
360:
361:
362: if (!\is_dir($this->runtimeDir))
363:      \mkdir($this->runtimeDir, 0700, true);
364: 
365:
366:   return $this-.runtimeDir;
Exception trace:

1 mkdir ("c:/WINDOWS/TEMP/psysh")
c:\xampp\php\codehub\vendor\psy\psysh\configuration.php:363

2 Psys\configuration::getRuntimedir()
  c:\xampp\php\codehub\vendor\psy\psysh\src\shekk.php:198
```

When i try to run PHP artisan tinker command that was the error I got.

Can any one help me out?

Comment: Can you share your configuration.php without security informations?